# Why is XEX not used instead of CTR?

Tags: encryption, modes-of-operation

As far as I know the only disadvantage that XEX has when compared to CTR is that you need a block cipher/permutation while CTR is fine with just a hash function. Meanwhile XEX offers the advantage that it is more misuse-resistant (reuse of the counter/nonce breaks CTR but this is not an issue with XEX) and less malleabile. Considering that, why is XEX almost never used outside of disk encryption?

Comment: Note that CTR needs a _pseudo-random function_, that is a function that takes a random key and some non-random input and produces some random-looking output. A hash function usually doesn't satisfy this API with only one input...

Comment: @SEJPM no, but HMAC does, wrapped around a hash function, I would consider that to fit the bill for "implementing CTR with hash functions": https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29232/implementing-5-modes-of-operation-with-a-hash-function/29244#29244

Comment: Another place that XEX is used is when you might have a noisy channel.  Let's say that you have a sensor in a remote location.  You'll use XEX because you might lose the comm link on the order of hours.

Comment: @SEJPM That did not stop Salsa20.

Comment: @bdegnan Please elaborate. Why would CTR not be acceptable in this situation?

Comment: @user79087 You don't know the counter.]

Comment: @bdegnan You have a counter in XEX too though. In addition they could just write the counter in front of the block in plaintext.

Comment: @user79087 You have a sector address and an index.   The sector is the random number generator sequence that's used for noise in CDMA or as a session ID for RFID, and the block is the data request.  It's not just a blind stream, as what is generally assumed by CTR.

Answer (score 4):

If CPA-security is sufficient, then CTR is sufficient. If you need authenticated encryption (or CCA), then neither XEX/XTS nor CTR is sufficient and you should be using AES-GCM or something similar. In general, as soon as you want something that is "less malleable" then you consider malleability a threat and you should be using authenticated encryption. If you are worried about nonce misuse resistance, then likewise you should be using such a scheme (SIV or GCM-SIV, etc.).

There is just no good reason to use XEX/XTS, except when you have a severe limitation like in disk encryption that you cannot increase the sector size.

Comment: This does not answer my question as it does not mention any drawback of XEX compared to CTR. As for XEX/CTR not being sufficient, adding a mac-tag is the most trivial thing. In addition as far as I know nobody uses GCM-SIV.

Comment: It does answer your question. CTR is much simpler and faster and sufficient for CPA. You mentioned malleability, so this is apparently a goal, but XEX/XTS does not solve it. Yes you can add a MAC but why would you not use a much faster and standard scheme. Finally, Google uses GCM-SIV in QUIC, and AWS uses a variant of GCM-SIV for encryption.